# How to pass value of vb checkbox to excel checkbox

Tags: vb.net, excel, checkbox, vba

I've tried the things here on the internet but I still can't make it work.

My code is like this:

```
Dim oXL As Excel.Application
Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim oRng As Excel.Range

If Center_for_Patient_PartnershipsCboxCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
    oSheet.OLEObjects("Check Box 1").Object.Value = 1
Else
    oSheet.OLEObjects("Check Box 1").Object.Value = 0
End If`
```

Comment: Just a quick note, would you consider shortening the code a bit? Not that it really matters but for example say ` checkbox1.checked = true`. Just thought simplifying code will make it easier to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a Form Control check box:

```
oSheet.Shapes("Check box 1").ControlFormat.Value = 0  'Uncheck
oSheet.Shapes("Check box 1").ControlFormat.Value = 1  'Check
```

---

If it's an Active X check box:

```
oSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Value = 0  'Uncheck
oSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox1").Object.Value = 1  'Check
```

---

Notice that the name of the active x control can't have spaces but the form control check box can.  This is why I provided both answers.

Comment: Do you mean the active x can't  have spaces? coz u said both can